# Deploying Django App Using Google Cloud Run - gcloud builds submit error

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've followed the tutorial for deploying Django on Cloud Run (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django), and I followed the exact instructions up to "Build your application image" on Step 7: "Configure, build and run migration steps".

When running the command:
`gcloud builds submit --pack image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myimage`

```
[builder]   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
[builder]   │ exit code: 1
[builder]   ╰─> [25 lines of output]
[builder]       /layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
[builder]         warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
[builder]       running egg_info
[builder]       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xoozdk2u/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
[builder]       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xoozdk2u/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
[builder]       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xoozdk2u/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
[builder]       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xoozdk2u/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
[builder]       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xoozdk2u/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
[builder]
[builder]       Error: pg_config executable not found.
[builder]
[builder]       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
[builder]       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
[builder]       option:
[builder]
[builder]           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
[builder]
[builder]       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
[builder]
[builder]       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
[builder]       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
[builder]
[builder]       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
[builder]       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
[builder]
[builder]       [end of output]
[builder]
[builder]   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[builder] error: metadata-generation-failed
[builder]
[builder] × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
[builder] ╰─> See above for output.
[builder]
[builder] note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
[builder] hint: See above for details.
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] Sorry your project couldn't be built.
[builder] Our documentation explains ways to configure Buildpacks to better recognise your project:
[builder]  -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/blob/main/README.md
[builder] If you think you've found an issue, please report it:
[builder]  -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks/issues/new
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 51
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build e6025313-e189-4df7-95e9-6389fbc62b7a completed with status "FAILURE"
```

This is preventing me from continuing to the next step, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

I've tried pip installing psycopg2-binary as the error suggests, however it made not difference and because it's Google Cloud I wouldn't want to mess around with too many unorthodox installs, perhaps there's something I'm missing here? I've searched everywhere, and I haven't run into this exact issue.

Answer (score -1):

The version of psycopg2-binary you're using hasn't been built for that version of Python, so the installation from source fires, and is failing.

Update to the latest version of psycopg2-binary from pypi, https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/#history, and you should be able to use the prebuilt wheel, thus avoiding this error.